# RESTeasy: return file

Tags: file, internet-explorer, rest, resteasy

I want to retrun a file using RESTeasy, so I have the following method:

```
    @Path("/export/{id}/list.xlsx")
@Produces("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
@GET
@NoCache
public Response exportList(
        @PathParam(value = "id") Long m,
        @QueryParam("p1") String p1,
        @QueryParam("p2") String p2,
            ......
        ){...body...}
```

The method accepts a lot of parameters.
So.. it works fine, but only in Mozila or Chrome. 
IE suggest me saving file with a weird name (not **list..xslx** but the whole **url string**)! And when I press "Save as" I get "SocketWriteError".
Have anybody faced such a problem before? Maybe it connects with huge param list?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Remove NoCache annotation)